# How to create multiple resource in a crossplane composition form an input array?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, crossplane

I have crossplane XRD where I want to create the same set of resources in multiple AWS regions

```yaml
apiVersion: aws.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: XFoo
metadata: 
  name: green-foo
spec: 
  clusters: 
    regions: 
      - us-east-1
      - us-east-2
      - us-west-2
```

In the crossplane composition how do I create a resource for each of the regions in the `clusters.regions` array? Is there some way to iterate over the inputs and stamp out a resource for each item?

Comment: Hey,

Do you get to solve this issue? I am also looking for same kind of solution.

Comment: functions is the only way to do this. but I have not gotten around to testing the function setup. I managed to redesign my xrd to avoid the array, given that that functions were alpha when I asked the question. see https://docs.crossplane.io/knowledge-base/guides/composition-functions/